# What is the difference between prepared statement and parameterized query in Npgsql?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I'd like to get clarification on whether parameterized queries are the same as prepared statements in Npgsql. If I write the following, without an explicit `cmd.Prepare()`:

```
var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE foo SET bar=@bar;");
cmd.Parameters.Add("bar", 1);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Without considering the effects of [automatic preparation](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/prepare.html#automatic-preparation), is the above a prepared statement internally? Conversely, if automatic preparation takes effect, does it apply to all queries regardless of whether it is parameterized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are two completely orthogonal things. Parameterizing is about extracting values out of the SQL, replacing them with a placeholder (`@bar`) which refers to the data out-of-band. This protects against SQL injection, and also transfers the data in a more efficient binary format, rather than encoding it as a string within the SQL.

Prepared statements are about preparing a SQL once, and then reusing the same prepared statement to avoid the overhead of the database parsing and planning the SQL each time.

> Without considering the effects of automatic preparation, is the above a prepared statement internally?

Without automatic preparation, this query executes unprepared, even though it has parameters.

> Conversely, if automatic preparation takes effect, does it apply to all queries regardless of whether it is parameterized?

Yes - queries without any parameters can also get prepared. This is beneficial since a query may be complex to parse/plan regardless of whether it has parameters or not.